# Broken Macports recover: all activated ports shows 'command not found'

Tags: macos, bash, macports, sudo

My MacPort installed all these packages:
  a52dec @0.7.4_0 (active)
  apache2 @2.2.25_0+preforkmpm (active)........xz @5.0.5_0 (active)
  yasm @1.2.0_0 (active)
  zlib @1.2.8_0 (active)

But after I accidentally removed these:
    rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git

I can still see the activated ports but no one can run, showing a 'command not found' instead.

How to re-link these ports to my bash command?

Comment: Macports does not use or see anythong in /usr/local so I suspect there is something else you have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the `/opt/local/bin`, `/opt/local/lib`, etc., for the port contents. The directories you have removed should not affect MacPorts. Check that your `~/.profile` `PATH` variable is valid. `port list installed` is a place to start.

Comment: Thanks! I recovered it from adding the port directories to .bash_profile after realising the .profile could not affect $PATH. I've tried etc/paths, launchd.conf or .profile ..... no one made it. only for .bash_profile. I know this is not normal...